# RegEx to Remove All Text Between Set Characters

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm using the Regex functionality in Notepad++ to delete all characters between specific characters. For example I have text file with the following line:

```
table.column NOT IN ('AB1','CD2')$D$AB1,CD2$X$
```

I would like to locate the text contained within **$D$** & **$X$** giving me a selection of

```
$D$AB1,CD2$X$
```

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to achieve this?

Many thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the limited information from you example, I would suggest this:

Find what: `(.*?\$D\$).*(\$X\$.*)`

Replace with: `\1TEST\2`

Basically, the *find* expression consists of two capturing blocks ending and starting around the part you want to replace, and the *replace* expression reconstructs the line with your replacement.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply - I've tried this and it removes the text preceding  the  $D$...$X$ block. Ideally I would like only the text between  $D$ & $X$ removed

Comment: @aphrek I thought you wanted to get `$D$AB1,CD2$X$`. Could you give an example of the desired result?

Comment: Hi, sorry my explanation wasnt great. I would like to replace text within the $D$ and $X$. first example (replacing existing text with string TEST): `table.column NOT IN ('AB1','CD2')$D$AB1,CD2$X$` should return `table.column NOT IN ('AB1','CD2')$D$TEST$X$` another example: `table.column NOT IN ('CF1','GD2')$D$CF1,GD2$X$ AND table.amount > 0` should return `table.column NOT IN ('CF1','GD2')$D$TEST$X$ AND table.amount > 0`

Comment: @aphrek updated answer according to your last comment